# Composition shows mask instead of content

Tags: after-effects

I have the following project layout:

```
[null]
[comp1]
  mask/matte
  texture
```

When I'm inside the comp1 I see the content correctly. But in my main project view, I just see the mask(!) (black/white) instead of the content! What might be wrong here?

Comment: Can you post screen shots by any chance?  There are lots of check boxes and such on the layers that could be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether you have [Collapse Transformations](http://www.digitalsandwich.net/portfolio/ae-quicktip-collapse-transformations/) enabled in your comp1.  It's a litte sun icon:

[image: Screenshot of a comp showing the collapse transformations icon]